# How to verify if a route has received a prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a method in GridRow.vue that redirects to a route passing params:

```
    redirectWithData () {
        this.$router.push({
            name: 'payment.request',
            params: {
                periodFrom: this.data.periodFrom,
                periodTo: this.data.periodTo,
                receipt: this.data.receipt
            }
        })
    }
```

But, when i refresh the page i lose that params, i don't know how to save that params in the new route called, or how to check if that route has received those params and, if not, redirect to another route

I receive params in RequestPayment.vue:

```
props: {
    periodFrom: String,
    periodTo: String,
    receipt: Number
}
```

In vue router i just setted props: true for RequestPayment.vue i tried to put a navigation guard but no success

```
{
    component: RequestPayment,
    name: 'payment.request',
    path: '/pagamentos/solicitar',
    props: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a param in **Vue.JS** through router you must pass it using the url. For example:

```
{
    /* router.js */
    component: RequestPayment,
    name: 'payment.request',
    path: '/pagamentos/solicitar/:periodFrom/:periodTo/:receipt',
    props: true
}
```

By doing that, whenever **Vue** renders the component it'll match the props inside the component with the props with the route, that's why you must use the exact same name for props on router and inside the component.

If the props are passed or controlled in a different way, you should consider using **Vuex**.